# Why does @Html.EnumDropDownListFor add a blank(0) selection when you have numerically defined values for an enum?

Tags: .net, enums, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have two enums:

```
public enum AnnouncementType
{
    All = 1,
    Corporate = 2,
    Franchisee = 3
}

public enum AnnouncementLevel
{
    Urgent,
    Normal
}
```

The first one, when using @Html.EnumDropDownListFor will add a blank option to the top of drop-down.  The second behaves as expected and does not add the blank option.  It has something to do with setting the values of the enum.  Is there a way to get it to behave the same as not having values assigned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0` is the default value for an enum.  In the second example, `Urgent` is `0`.  So it doesn't need to add one.  In the first example, there is no `0`, so it creates it for you.